# does python 2.5 have an equivalent to Tcl's uplevel command?

Tags: python, tcl, uplevel

Does python have an equivalent to Tcl's uplevel command? For those who don't know, the "uplevel" command lets you run code in the context of the caller. Here's how it might look in python:

```
def foo():
    answer = 0
    print "answer is", answer # should print 0
    bar()
    print "answer is", answer # should print 42


def bar():
    uplevel("answer = 42")
```

It's more than just setting variables, however, so I'm not looking for a solution that merely alters a dictionary. I want to be able to execute any code.

Comment: If you could explain what Tcl's uplevel command does you might get answers of Python programmers who don't know Tcl too.

Comment: There are some evil ways to do it, but maybe you could describe your original problem so we could find a more pythonic solution?

Comment: @Michal Kwiatkowski: I hate to do this, by my original problem is, I need to run code in the context of the caller. :-\ ("need" is relative, more like "want"). I have a third party library that calls my own function at certain times. I want this function to be able to alter the environment of the caller. In effect, create a debugger by allowing my function to change the value of variables and/or call other functions before allowing the caller to continue.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: You're probably going to have to play around with stack frames and suchlike. I don't know enough about it to be helpful, but that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: def uplevel(var,val): inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[2][0].f_locals[var]=val didnt work

Comment: I'd be really surprised if it was emulatable, given that it allows arbitrary execution of arbitrary code anywhere in the caller stack. (Well, within the same interpreter; it can't cross security partitions.) It's not used that way by most code, of course, but an exceptionally powerful mechanism.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: yeah. I probably use uplevel once every two or three years, if that. But when I use it, it is a godsend. I was hoping Python had something equivalent. Apparently not. Time for Plan B.

Comment: @Bryan: Me on the other hand, uplevel is one of the first tools I reach for when given a problem. It makes it easy to express intent when what you're trying to do is encoded in the control structure itself (it's the reason foreach is becoming so popular in other languages these days). The only problem is it's slow. And the problem with that is every time I think my code is not speed critical someone else starts using it to parse gigabytes of data :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, what you ask is not possible (with the results you no doubt expect).  E.g., imagine the "any code" is `x = 23`.  Will this add a new variable `x` to your caller's set of local variables, assuming you do find a black-magical way to execute this code "in the caller"?  No it won't -- **the** crucial optimization performed by the Python compiler is to define once and for all, when `def` executes, the exact set of local variables (all the barenames that get assigned, or otherwise bound, in the function's body), and turn every access and setting to those barenames into very fast indexing into the stackframe.  (You *could* systematically defeat that crucial optimization e.g. by having an `exec ''` at the start of every possible caller -- and see your system's performance crash through the floor in consequence).

*Except* for assigning to the caller's local barenames, `exec thecode in thelocals, theglobals` may do roughly what you want, and the `inspect` module lets you get the locals and globals of the caller in a semi-reasonable way (in as far as deep black magic -- which would make me go postal on any coworker suggesting it be perpetrated in production code -- can ever be honored with the undeserved praise of calling it "semi-reasonable", that is;-).

But you do specify "I want to be able to execute any code." and the only solution to *that* unambiguous specification (and thanks for being so precise, as it makes answering easier!) is: then, use a different programming language.

Comment: Modyfing locals is indeed not possible, at least not without going to C level. Let me just add those two links for further read: http://bugs.python.org/issue1654367 and http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2007-February/070885.html

Comment: this answer is a bit too preachy to be useful IMHO.

Comment: @Bryan, you're entitled to your opinion and to express it, of course, but I am similarly entitled to disagree vehemently -- and to absolutely detest your actions, summarized as: you claim you want to run **any** code; I show you precisely that you can't do so and why; you post a self-answer (dubious practice indeed anyway) which does **not** meet your own reqs, and instead of thanking me for stopping you from wasting your time trying otherwise, criticize and downvote me. Proper non-preachy reactions would require violence, physical or at least verbal, so I'd rather be preachy instead.

Comment: dubious to answer my own question? Doesn't SO have a badge for that? I think it's also mentioned in the FAQ it's OK. As to it not answering my original question, you're right. If I could have created a fully working answer I would, but I couldn't. I posted what I had and asked if anyone can improve on it. As for thanking you for stopping me from wasting my time.. ? My time wasn't wasted; I learned something. And how do you know it was me that downvoted you? Someone upvoted my comment so I'm not the only one who didn't like your answer.

Comment: I didn't upvote your answer because, frankly I wasn't sure it was authoritative or correct. Like I said, it came off a bit preachy which lead me to mistrust the answer a little. I just need facts here, not opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Is the third party library written in Python? If yes, you could rewrite and rebind the function "foo" at runtime with your own implementation. Like so:

```
import third_party

original_foo = third_party.foo
def my_foo(*args, **kwds):
    # do your magic...
    original_foo(*args, **kwds)
third_party.foo = my_foo
```

I guess monkey-patching is slighly better than rewriting frame locals. ;)

Comment: yes, it is written in python. Monkeypatching is not the solution I'm looking for though.

Comment: As Alex explained to you, you're not going to find a way to write `uplevel` because of the way CPython is implemented. You need approach the problem differently to find a solution.

Comment: Kwiatkowski: Thanks, but I'm not looking for a solution to my problem, I'm looking for the answer to the question "Does python have uplevel-like functionality?". The use of uplevel-like functionality is one of several possible solutions I'm mulling over. I'm not a newbie asking you to do my work for me, I'm just trying to gather facts about a language I do not yet have a deep understanding of.

Comment: OK, so the answer to your question is "not in pure Python" and details are in Alex's answer. For even more detail you'd have to dig into CPython source code, which is quite readable. I'm guessing you *could* do some evil stuff on the C level (or with ctypes), but locals access is a low level implementation detail. For example, an optimizing interpreter could inline locals and there would be nothing left to assign to. It's best not to rely on them being there.