# Does Python 3.8 has an equivalent of TCL uplevel

Tags: python-3.x, tcl, uplevel

This is equivalent to the question asked about Python 2.5 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794461/does-python-2-5-have-an-equivalent-to-tcls-uplevel-command#3794660).
However, I am interested if this functionality has been added in Python 3.8., or beforehand.

Comment: Smells like an XY problem. Explain *what* you're wanting to do in python and someone might be able to help with an idiomatic approach.

Comment: Python has nothing like `uplevel`; it uses a completely different set of principles for organizing code (especially for name binding) that precludes that sort of thing. But that's not normally a problem; you do things in a different way. ***What are you trying to do?*** Bigger picture please; you're in a dead end and need to back up just a little way and try an alternate path.

Comment: I was trying to migrate from TCL to Python. So, I went for minimal changes.